# Mocked CloseableHttpClient still passes connection to real server while testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

i try to test a method which uses a CloseableHttpClient Connection. I decided to go for Mockito and mocked all relevant classes and methods. But still, as soon as I start the test it goes straight to the real server instead of being intercepted by the mocked CloseableHttpClient.

The test

```
  @Test
    public void testBid() throws IOException {
        //given:
        HttpGet httpGet = mock(HttpGet.class);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = mock(HttpResponse.class);

        StatusLine statusLine = mock(StatusLine.class);

        ObserverImp observer = mock(ObserverImp.class);

        CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
        CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);

        //and:
        when(statusLine.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(200);
        when(httpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(statusLine);
        when(closeableHttpClient.execute(httpGet)).thenReturn(closeableHttpResponse);
        when(observer.getKey()).thenReturn("##213");


        Buy buy = new Buy(observer);
        buy.bid(14455);
    }
```

And the related **Implementation**

```
public void buy(double price) {
        String queryArgs = "command=order&amount=1" + "&price=" + String.valueOf(price); // generates query

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("wwww.hm.edu/projectGroup1");
        post.addHeader("Key", observer.getKey());
        try {
            post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(queryArgs.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in run");
        }
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("command", "order"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("amount", "1"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", String.valueOf(price)));
        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(entity.getContent());
            String orderNumber = "";
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                orderNumber = in.nextLine();
            }
            String[] findOrderNumber = orderNumber.split(".");
            long lastOrderNumber = -1;
            try {
                lastOrderNumber = Long.valueOf(findOrderNumber[3]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                System.out.println("NumberFormatException");
            } finally {
                if (lastOrderNumber != -1) {
                    observer.setOrderNumber(lastOrderNumber);
                }
            }
            in.close();
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            httpClient.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured during process");
        }
    }
```

I tried several code snippets of tests I found in tutorials or similar questions here but with no success. Can you please tell me what I do wrong here?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `CloseableHttpClient httpClient` via constructor:

```
public class Buy {
    private ObserverImp observer;
    private CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

    public Buy (ObserverImp observer, CloseableHttpClient httpClient) {
       this.observer = observer;
       this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public void buy(double price) {
       ...

       // Comment or remove the line below and use the injected instead...
       // CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

       ...
    }
}
```

And to test it, follows:

```
@Test
public void testBid() throws IOException {
    //given:
    HttpGet httpGet = mock(HttpGet.class);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = mock(HttpResponse.class);

    StatusLine statusLine = mock(StatusLine.class);

    ObserverImp observer = mock(ObserverImp.class);

    CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
    CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);

    //and:
    when(statusLine.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(200);
    when(httpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(statusLine);
    when(closeableHttpClient.execute(httpGet)).thenReturn(closeableHttpResponse);
    when(observer.getKey()).thenReturn("##213");


    Buy buy = new Buy(observer, closeableHttpClient);
    buy.bid(14455);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Should I change the CTOR only for testing or is it a general change? Or can I create a second CTOR (overloading) What is the way good coder go :) ?

Comment: I just saw that I have to do the same with HttpPost then correct?

Comment: You're welcome. There is no right answer. But you can overload the constructor, defining one that receives only the `OberserverImp` instance, like `Buy(ObserverImp obs) { this(obs, HttpClients.createDefault()); }`. In general, you invoke the only-one-arg-constructor. To test, you invoke the two-args-constructor. See my point?

Comment: Yes :) so my target of the question is, if its a good design decision to create a CTOR only for testing purposes?

Comment: The _good practice_ is [*Dependency Inversion Principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) and in your case inverting the http client dep is good practice so that in future if you have to uses SecureHttpClient, then you dont have to modify your `buy' code. One more thing, adding constructors for UT is _OK_ as long as you are hiding them by making package private.

Answer (score 0):

In your `buy` method, you're creating `httpClient` using static method, like this

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

now everytime you call `buy` the *real* http client gets created and it call real services. Instead, you should pass `httpClient` as dependency as mock `httpClient` from your test code, like

```
public void buy(double price, HttpClient httpClient) {
..
}
```

and in test:

```
public void test() {

    HttpClient httpClient = mock(HttpClient.class)
    // mock the behavour

    // SUT
    buy(..., httpClient);

}
```